# Xamarin plugin for Unity

Tags: c#, android, plugins, unity-game-engine, xamarin

I want to create a Xamarin Android plugin for Unity. I was able to do that whith simple tasks(generating random numbers or sth like that), but when I tryied to build a more complex dll file and use it into unity, there were some errors in Unity.

```
////This is the plugin that I have created in Xamarin
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Plugin
{
    public class CallAction : Activity
    {
        public void Call()
        {
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("tel:1112223333");
            var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionDial, uri);
            StartActivity (intent);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I used it into Unity

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Plugin;


public class PluginTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void CallButton()
    {
        CallAction c = new CallAction ();
        c.Call ();
    }
}
```

And this is the error that Unity gave me

```
Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' or one of its dependencies.

File name: 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:InternalGetType (System.Reflection.Module,string,bool,bool)

  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType (System.String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.GetTypeInAssembly (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.LookupTypeReflection (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.String name, Location loc, Boolean must_be_unique) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.LookupTypeReflection (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.String name, Location loc, Boolean must_be_unique) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Namespace.LookupType (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.String name, Location loc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Namespace.Lookup (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.String name, Location loc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.NamespaceEntry.Lookup (System.String name, Location loc, Boolean ignore_cs0104) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.NamespaceEntry.LookupNamespaceOrType (System.String name, Location loc, Boolean ignore_cs0104) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.DeclSpace.LookupNamespaceOrType (System.String name, Location loc, Boolean ignore_cs0104) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.DeclSpace.LookupNamespaceOrType (System.String name, Location loc, Boolean ignore_cs0104) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.MemberCore.LookupNamespaceOrType (System.String name, Location loc, Boolean ignore_cs0104) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Method.LookupNamespaceOrType (System.String name, Location loc, Boolean ignore_cs0104) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext.LookupNamespaceOrType (System.String name, Location loc, Boolean ignore_cs0104) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.SimpleName.ResolveAsTypeStep (IMemberContext ec, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Expression.ResolveAsBaseTerminal (IMemberContext ec, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Expression.ResolveAsTypeTerminal (IMemberContext ec, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Expression.ResolveAsContextualType (IMemberContext rc, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.LocalInfo.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Block.ResolveMeta (Mono.CSharp.BlockContext ec, Int32 offset) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.ToplevelBlock.ResolveMeta (Mono.CSharp.BlockContext ec, Mono.CSharp.ParametersCompiled ip) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.ToplevelBlock.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.FlowBranching parent, Mono.CSharp.BlockContext rc, Mono.CSharp.ParametersCompiled ip, IMethodData md) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do? And if so, what am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: One thing: I would just suggest: is it *really* necessary to make a plugin? What are you trying to achieve?  All the world's games are made with Unity, with no plugins you know?

Comment: Some functionalities like let's say calling someone directly from my Unity app, or a sharing system that allows user to share my app on different social medias or a notification system like Toasts and so on. Anyway is it possible what I am trying to do? Thank you.

Comment: @RaducuMihai did you ever get this working?

Comment: Nope. I can't figure out a solution for this.